# Pivot HIVE tables with Data

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table :

| temperature | date |
| --- | --- |
| 17.1 | 2024-01-01 |
| 17.7 | 2024-01-02 |
| 16.2 | 2024-01-03 |

I would like to transform (pivot table) one time, like:

| 2024-01-01 | 2024-01-02 | 2024-01-03 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17.1 | 17.7 | 16.2 |

Please assist how to pivot table, we have a lot timestamps from 2024-01-01 to 2024-03-03?

I am looking the best way to pivot timeserias table

Comment: So what have you tried and what specific issue are you facing?

Comment: Issue with hardcoded date columns, instead of getting it dynamicly

Comment: If you don’t want to hardcode the date columns then you’d need to use dynamic SQL to generate the SQL you want and execute it. If you get stuck doing this then update your question with what you do manage to write